# Binary Search Tree Frequency Counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, search, tree, binary

I need to read a text file, strip the unnecessary punctuation, lowercase the words and use binary search tree function to make a word binary search tree that consists of the words in the file.

We are asked to count the frequency of recurring words and asked for a total word count and total unique word count.

So far I've got the punctuation resolved, file read done, lowercase done, binary search tree basically done and I just need to figure out how to implement the "frequency" counter in the code.

My code is as follows:

```
class BSearchTree :
class _Node :
    def __init__(self, word, left = None, right = None) :
        self._word = word
        self._count = 0
        self._left = left
        self._right = right

def __init__(self) :
    self._root = None
    self._wordc = 0
    self._each = 0

def isEmpty(self) :
    return self._root == None


def search(self, word) :
    probe = self._root
    while (probe != None) :
        if word == probe._word :
            return probe
        if word < probe._value :
            probe = probe._left
        else : 
            probe = probe._right
    return None     

def insert(self, word) :
    if self.isEmpty() :
        self._root = self._Node(word)
        self._root._freq += 1 <- is this correct?
        return

    parent = None               #to keep track of parent
                                #we need above information to adjust 
                                #link of parent of new node later

    probe = self._root
    while (probe != None) :
        if word < probe._word :     # go to left tree
            parent = probe          # before we go to child, save parent
            probe = probe._left
        elif word > probe._word :   # go to right tree
            parent = probe          # before we go to child, save parent
            probe = probe._right

    if (word < parent._word) :      #new value will be new left child
        parent._left = self._Node(word)
    else :    #new value will be new right child
        parent._right = self._Node(word)
```

cause formatting is killing me, this is the latter part of it.

```
class NotPresent(Exception) :
pass

def main():
t=BST()

file = open("sample.txt")           
line = file.readline()                      
file.close()                            


#for word in line:
#   t.insert(word)
# Line above crashes program because there are too many 
# words to add. Lines on bottom tests BST class
t.insert('all')
t.insert('high')
t.insert('fly')
t.insert('can')
t.insert('boars')
#t.insert('all') <- how do i handle duplicates by making 
t.inOrder()        #extras add to the nodes frequency?
```

Thank you for helping/trying to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it's better to initialize a `Node`'s `_freq` by 1 than doing that in in `BST`'s `insert()`

(1 more: In python coding convention, white spaces in writing default argument values are not recommended.)

```
    def __init__(self, word, left=None, right=None) :
        self._word = word
        self._freq = 1
        self._left = left
        self._right = right
```

and just add the last 3 lines:

```
    probe = self._root
    while (probe != None) :
        if word < probe._word :     # go to left tree
            parent = probe          # before we go to child, save parent
            probe = probe._left
        elif word > probe._word :   # go to right tree
            parent = probe          # before we go to child, save parent
            probe = probe._right
        else:
            probe._freq += 1
            return
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I just have to be able to display the frequency counter for each word and display both total number of words and unique words.

Comment: @bluekozo You already wrote in-order traversal. Remaining tasks are much easier than implementing BST.

Comment: i was able to figure out how to print the words and frequency beside them. Any tips on how I can get around to counting all of the words and all of the unique words/strings?

Comment: @bluekozo Accumulate the frequencies of each word while printing. Words with frequency 1 are unique. So you need two counters.